# image gallery using table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I am creating an app which is having a module some thing like a image gallery. When I parsed an XML it gives some number of images ,say 10 , and displayed in table's row. Now when select a row from table, in my next view it should display 10 image's thumbnails in a table's row. One row should contain 4 small image and so on.

any good programming suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need re-order function about those cells, then you can implement by subclassing UITableviewCell, in which each cell contains 4 buttons. The touch-up inside message can be send by delegate.

Update:

A custom cell example:

```
  @protocol MyCellDelegate <NSObject>
  - (void)notifyCell:(MyCell *)cell didTouchupInside:(UIButton *)innerButton;
  @end

  @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell {
  @private
      // easy to understand button example
      // you can use array or dictionary to manage your buttons.
      UIButton *mButton1;
      UIButton *mButton2;
      UIButton *mButton3;
      UIButton *mButton4;

      // Other member variables.
  }

  @property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;

  - (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier delegate:(id)delegate;

  @end
```

Through MyCellDelegate, the client can know what happens on MyCell objects.

Comment: and what I have do if i want to select a particular image to be displayed in next view. Which properties of uibutton I have to specify for this purpose..

Comment: You can add target and action to UIButton, and transfer those event by delegate. You can define a custom protocol for this subclassing cell for send message by delegate.

Answer (score 3):

Use TTThumbsViewController from Three20:
https://github.com/facebook/three20/

Tutorial:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-photo-gallery-three20/

Feels native and does exactly what you need:

[image]